# Reset Cache of Basis CHIPs (/UI2/CHIP_CSTAT) is locked by user xxxx in Activating "Manage Purchase Orders"

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-erp, sap-basis

I am unable to activate standard Fiori app "Manage Purchase Orders". I have tried to solve the issue by doing steps given in https://scn.sap.com/thread/3891180 but it's still not working.

After clicking on the list item it should navigate to other page but it's giving error on console:

> 403(forbidden)

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your user is probably authenticated, but not permitted, to perform the requested operation. You might check, for example, the file system of the web server, if you are denied access to the requested resource.